# Object is possible undefined? Typescript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement this function but I keep getting this undefined error.

```
let item: OrderItem | undefined;

item = this.order.items.find(o => o.productNumber === product.productNumber);

if (item !== undefined) {
    item.quantity++;//Error
} else {//Something}
```

The error happens near the item.quantity++;
These are the things I tried

```
if (!item) {
    item.quantity++;

if (item) {
    item.quantity++;
```

any help is appreciated.

**Order.ts**

```
export class OrderItem {
    Id: number | undefined;
    productId: number | undefined;
    productNumber: number | undefined;
    productName: string | undefined;
    productPicture: string | undefined;
    productPrice: number | undefined;
    productDescription: string | undefined;
    quantity: number | undefined;
    unitPrice: number | undefined;
}

export class Order {
    orderId: number | undefined;
    orderNumber: string | undefined;
    orderDate: Date = new Date();
    orderTotal: number | undefined;
    /*orderStatus: string | undefined;*/
    items: OrderItem[] = [];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `if(!item)`?

Comment: Yeah did not work @laudebugs

Comment: is `quantity` an optional member of the `OrderItem` type?

Comment: No I will update the question @laudebugs

Comment: typescript will always expect to get undefined from a .find() operation so maybe try item?.quantity++;

Comment: Tried that too @msmoore I am getting the Object is possible undefined? and the operand of the increment or decrement operator may not be an optional property access errors

Comment: Have you tried if (item?.quantity) { item.quantity++; } else { ... }. Have you also logged what .find() returns to make sure it's an object with a key of quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `quantity` is typed as `number | undefined` `item.quantity` may be `undefined`. Trying to increment this with `item.quantity++` would result in `NaN` and therefor not be what you expected here.

To satisfy the type checker here trying checking that `item.quantity` is not `undefined`:

```ts
if (item?.quantity !== undefined) {
  item.quantity++;
}
```

(Note the use of [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here)